# How to get a result of query executed with `--nosync` option by bq command line?

Tags: google-bigquery

I executed an async batch query with bq command line.

```
$ bq --nosync --format csv query --max_rows 100000000 --use_cache --batch "(my SELECT statement here)"
Successfully started query (Job ID here)
```

After a while, `bq wait JOB_ID` returns `Current status: DONE`, and `bq show -j JOB_ID` returns following:

```
Job JOB_ID

  Job Type    State      Start Time      Duration   Bytes Processed
 ---------- --------- ----------------- ---------- -----------------
  query      SUCCESS   24 Feb 10:53:59   0:00:09    117196741
```

Then, How can I get the result of the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a batched query (they take longer to execute, but at a substantially lower cost) the line you pasted is correct:

```
bq --nosync query --max_rows 100000000 --use_cache --batch "SELECT 1+1 AS addition, 10-1 AS subs"

Successfully started query ggg:bqjob_r369f07bc39ef3b26_000_1
```

Using the bq command, now you can use "head" to peek at the resulting values (see `bq --help head` for options):

```
bq --format csv head -j ggg:bqjob_r369f07bc39ef3b26_000_1

addition,subs
2,9
```

Comment: It seems that `--max_rows` option is required for `head` command to get more than 100 records.

Comment: This answer seems to contain wrong information. `--nosync` does not mean that the query is run as a "batched" query at a lower price. That's what the [`--batch` flag](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/running-queries#batch) does.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bq head --job JOB_ID`

Answer (score 0):

`--nosync` is used to start an asynchronous job, return ing the jobID